# I tried to display list of images in Listview but i have only the first item from the list

Tags: android, listview, retrofit

I am working with android and retrofit to call API web services the data was received successfully but when I tried to display the list of images in my layout the result is only the first images although the size of images array is upper .. 
My activities is : CityActivity get city info like name and description and list of city images.. 
and in city images, i have the problem which I asked about 
my code:
CityActivity:

```js
package com.example.android.travelandtourism.Activities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.android.travelandtourism.Adapters.ImagesAdapter;
import com.example.android.travelandtourism.Interfaces.IApi;
import com.example.android.travelandtourism.Models.City;
import com.example.android.travelandtourism.Models.Countries;
import com.example.android.travelandtourism.Models.Images;
import com.example.android.travelandtourism.R;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

/**
 * Created by haya on 29/08/2017.
 */

public class CityActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView listView;
    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://www.travel-tourism1.somee.com/api/";
    String url="http://www.travel-tourism1.somee.com";


    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("66yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
            .create();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

    IApi service = retrofit.create(IApi.class);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_city_info);

        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        int cityId = intent.getIntExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,0);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listCityImages);
        Call<ResponseValue> call = service.getCity(cityId);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseValue>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseValue> call, Response<ResponseValue> response) {
                listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ResponseValue cityResponse = response.body();
                City cc = cityResponse.getCity();
                TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCityInfoNameEn);
                tv1.setText(cc.getNameEn());
                TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCityInfoNameAr);
                tv2.setText(cc.getNameAr());
                TextView tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCityInfoDesEng);
                tv3.setText(cc.getDescriptionEn());
                TextView tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCityInfoDesAr);
                tv4.setText(cc.getDescriptionAr());

                ArrayList<Images> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                ArrayList<Images> images = cityResponse.getCity().getImages();
                arrayList.addAll(images);
              // final ImagesAdapter adapter = new ImagesAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row_image,arrayList);
                    ImagesAdapter adapter = new ImagesAdapter(getApplicationContext(),arrayList);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseValue> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });


    }
}
```

ImagesAdapter:

```js
package com.example.android.travelandtourism.Adapters;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.example.android.travelandtourism.Models.City;
import com.example.android.travelandtourism.Models.Images;
import com.example.android.travelandtourism.R;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by haya on 29/08/2017.
 */

public class ImagesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    String url = "http://www.travel-tourism1.somee.com";
    private Context context;
    private List<Images> imagesList;

    public ImagesAdapter(Context context,  List<Images> objects) {
      //  super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.imagesList = objects;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return imagesList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return imagesList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_image,parent,false);


        Images image = imagesList.get(position);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
        String imgPath = image.getPath().substring(1);
        Picasso.with(this.context).load(url+imgPath).resize(300,300).into(iv);


        return view;

    }


}
```

My layouts:
activity_city_info:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fillViewport="true">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="4dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvCityInfoNameEn"
        android:text="EngName"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvCityInfoNameAr"
        android:text="ArName"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvCityInfoDesEng"
        android:text="EngDes"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvCityInfoDesAr"
        android:text="ArDes"/>



    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listCityImages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:listitem="@layout/row_image"
        />

</LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>




<!--


-->
```

and finaly   row_image:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="4dp">




        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />




    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

any help! and thank you
Update
[image: imageList]

Comment: Actually what problem you are facing?

Comment: I can only get the first image from the list of images in listview in my layout... (one image from 3, for example)  @UpendraShah

Answer (score 1):

Add this methods in your ImageAdapter class:

```
 public class ImagesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

String url = "http://www.travel-tourism1.somee.com";
private Context context;
private List<Images> imagesList;

public ImagesAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Images> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.imagesList = objects;
}



@Override
public int getCount() {

    return imagesList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}

 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_image,parent,false);


    Images image = imagesList.get(position);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
    String imgPath = image.getPath().substring(1);
    Picasso.with(getContext()).load(url+imgPath).resize(300,300).into(iv);


    return view;

 }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay ... but I have this error 'getItem(int)' in '(My Package name).CustomDrawerAdapter' clashes with 'getItem(int)' in 'android.widget.ArrayAdapter'; attempting to use incompatible return type"  because my class extends ArrayAdapter<Images>, how I fix it ?

Comment: change it to BaseAdapter :=> public class ImagesAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {

Comment: @HayaSVU change this it to BaseAdapter :=> public class ImagesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Comment: Thank you for your help,, but my no thing is changed even when I do what Mr. Bapusaheb Shinde tell me to do in the second comment of you see it..

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {

    return imagesList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return imageList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay ... but I have this error 'getItem(int)' in '(My Package name).CustomDrawerAdapter' clashes with 'getItem(int)' in 'android.widget.ArrayAdapter'; attempting to use incompatible return type" because my class extends ArrayAdapter<Images>, how I fix it ?

Comment: Change it to BaseAdapter

Comment: sorry, but the problem is not resolved.. I don't know what I missed .. can you check my code in github please ? https://github.com/haya51033/TravelAndTourism-master1

Comment: change this :   final ImagesAdapter adapter = new ImagesAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row_image,arrayList); From your CityActivity to   ImagesAdapter adapter = new ImagesAdapter(getApplicationContext(),arrayList);

Comment: Again the problem not resolved :( , and I update the file in github.. I am sorry for that :|

Comment: please check size of list in adapter

Comment: I Checked it and the size is three in some item, but the display image is only one.. you can check my update question